# Can we add data to a room in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a 2 player game using express and socket.io . The game is a simple one and the data structure required is a matrix. Is there a way to attach this matrix to the room and make changes to it. Or should I attach the matrix to both the sockets, and proceed in that manner?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a supported way to add your own data to a room object.  You could certainly put the matrix on both socket.io objects and that would probably be the simplest solution.  That creates some limitations in that a socket could never be in more than one game and as soon as the users disconnect, the matrix is lost (perhaps those are OK limitations).

Another approach would be to use your own `Map` object where the key is the room name and the value is the matrix.  So, whenever you create a matrix for a new room, you just put it in your own map.

```
// create matrix map
let matrixMap = new Map();

// set a matrix for a room
matrixMap.set(roomName, newMatrix).

// get a matrix for a room
let matrix = matrixMap.get(roomName);
```